# Is there a way to enable Google API in a unsupported Device?

Tags: android, google-api, google-speech-api

I'm working with a robot that use a tablet with android to communicate, the problem is that the robot SDK say that Google Services are not supported, so is there a way to make Google Services work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. These devices are usually built without the necessary licences because the manufacturers don't want to abide by Google's terms. Even if you could get the Google Play Services APKs and install them, they don't work on "unsupported devices". Here's some more detailed information if you are interested:

https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2018/04/google-services-blocked-on-uncertified-devices/

Comment: thank you for your answer, well the speech to text by google is very powerful, i need to find something offline so...

Comment: i think i'll send the audio file to my java server and try to use google api from server